# how set a label image for group bar Jpgraph column chart in php

Tags: php, jpeg, jpgraph

here is  my jpgraph demo code:

```
<?php
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph.php');
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph_bar.php');

$datay1=array(35,160,0,0,0,0);
$datay2=array(35,190,190,190,190,190);
$datay3=array(20,70,70,140,230,260);

$graph = new Graph(450,200,'auto');    
$graph->SetScale("textlin");
$graph->SetShadow();
$graph->img->SetMargin(40,30,40,40);
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels($gDateLocale->GetShortMonth());

$graph->xaxis->title->Set('Year 2002');
$graph->xaxis->title->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_BOLD);

$graph->title->Set('Group bar plot');
$graph->title->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_BOLD);

$bplot1 = new BarPlot($datay1);
$bplot2 = new BarPlot($datay2);
$bplot3 = new BarPlot($datay3);

$bplot1->SetFillColor("orange");
$bplot2->SetFillColor("brown");
$bplot3->SetFillColor("darkgreen");

$gbarplot = new GroupBarPlot(array($bplot1,$bplot2,$bplot3));
$gbarplot->SetWidth(0.6);
$graph->Add($gbarplot);

$graph->Stroke();
?>
```

this code has no error and this is working perfectly...my problem is how can I set image labels for this group bars for identifying those color bars...

norml out put chart is this:[image]

Need set this label image:
[image]

I want this kind of final out put :
[image]

***How can I do it ????***

Comment: I need to mentioned which color is for what??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here my code:

```
<?php
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph.php');
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph_bar.php');

$datay1=array(35,160,0,0,0,0);
$datay2=array(35,190,190,190,190,190);
$datay3=array(20,70,70,140,230,260);

$graph = new Graph(450,200,'auto');    
$graph->SetScale("textlin");
$graph->SetShadow();
$graph->img->SetMargin(40,30,40,40);
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels($gDateLocale->GetShortMonth());

$graph->xaxis->title->Set('Year 2002');
$graph->xaxis->title->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_BOLD);

$graph->title->Set('Group bar plot');
$graph->title->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_BOLD);

$bplot1 = new BarPlot($datay1);
$bplot2 = new BarPlot($datay2);
$bplot3 = new BarPlot($datay3);

$bplot1->SetFillColor("orange");
$bplot2->SetFillColor("brown");
$bplot3->SetFillColor("darkgreen");

$gbarplot = new GroupBarPlot(array($bplot1,$bplot2,$bplot3));
$gbarplot->SetWidth(0.6);


$graph->legend->SetPos(0.12,0.01,'left','top');
$graph->legend->SetLayout(LEGEND_VERT);
$graph->legend->SetFrameWeight(1);

$bplot1->SetLegend("Pass");
$bplot2->SetLegend("Fail");
$bplot3->SetLegend("Not Eligible");


$graph->Add($gbarplot);

$graph->Stroke();
?>
```

generated chart is: [image: Test bar chart with legend]

i hope this will help you achieve your target.